# How to use join here

Tags: sql

I am having the below table

[image]

From this table I have to display Username and SupervisorName. I am having both `userID`, and `SuperviosrUid` in the same table.

My Expected Output is:

[image]

Comment: Just for the sample data given you can join your table to itself with different aliases. However, couldn't you have a hierarchy? How many levels of supervisors are there?

Comment: do you have user table and supervisor table - both linked to the table you showed us?

Comment: No both in same table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just join the table with itself:

```
SELECT u.Name As UserName,
       s.Name As SupervisorName
FROM dbo.TableName u
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TableName s
    ON u.SupervisorUID = s.UID
```

I've used a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for the case that a user could have no supervisor. If it cannot be `NULL` you can use `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks but your query does not shows the supervisor as a user

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi: sure, the supervisor with the UID=8 will also be shown as a user.

Answer (score 2):

According to your data just normally join the table to the same table on a different column:

```
select u.name as userName, 
       s.name as supervisorName
from my_table u
join my_table s
on u.SupervisorUID = s.UID
```

If you do have a case where there is no supervisor do a `left join`

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
select 
   name UserName, 
   (select name from tbl_name where UID=b.SuperviosrUid) SupervisorName 
from tbl_name b
```